# CSRF in Spring + Thymeleaf + Ajax + Restful API

Tags: ajax, spring, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have enabled CSRF in my Spring + Thymeleaf application. The good thing is that Thymeleaf automatically takes care of adding CSRF to every < form > in html. The problem is that Ajax calls submitting those forms are now failing and I want to know if there is a standard solution to this.

The other issue on the other hand is that my application is going to support Restful APIs. When I am enabling CSRF in my application, the authentication from client using API fails.
So the question is that is there a way to enable CSRF for web browsing and disable it for my Restful API?
On the other hand disabling the CSRF makes restful APIs vulnerable to attacks if the attacker knows about them. So what is the best practice here?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code and the errors you are receiving. Also its best to create separate questions to have as many community members see them as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For First Scenario to submit form using ajax call you need to manually add hidden input generated by csrf in form.
For second case you can exclude some url from interceptor in your case you can exclude url from CSRF interceptor.

exclude tag is present in spring 3.2

```
    <mvc:interceptor>
<mvc:exclude-mapping path="/your_url"/> 
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But the question is should I really disable CSRF for the restful api? The attacker would be still able to attack the system knowing the api from browser. What I would really like to have is support of CSRF protection in Restful api.